# How to build EF query expression for persistence model using specification for domain model

Tags: c#, domain-driven-design, specifications, repository

I have domain model `Task` in domain layer and persistence model `eTask` in infrastructure:

```
class Task : IAggregateRoot, EntityBase
{
    private string taskText;

    public Task(string taskText)
        :this(null, taskText)
    {          
    }

    public Task(object id, string taskText)
        :base(id)
    {
        //argument validation
        this.taskText = taskText;
    }

    //some business logic here
}
```

...

```
class eTask
{
    public Guid ID { get; set; }
    public string TaskText { get; set; }
}
```

I have repository interface `ITaskRepository` and its implementation that uses EF with persistence model `eTask` and maps `eTask` to `Task` when returning result items

```
interface ITaskRepository : IRepository<Task>
{
    IEnumerable<Task> GetTasksBySpecification(ISpecification<Task> spec);
}
```

The `ISpecification` interface is like:

```
interface ISpecification<T>
{
    Expression<Func<T, bool>> IsSatisfiedBy();
}
```

The problem is in `ITaskRepository.GetTasksBySpecification` implementation. I try to find out how to convert specification object `spec` to expression for Entity framework's entities `eTask`. How can I do that?

Comment: I would rename `eTask` into `Task` and start using it as Domain Model. Entity Framework allows you to write Domain Model first.

Comment: EF models must have public getters and setters, but this is not good for Domains which have some incapsulation, that is why I separate Domain Models and Persistence Models

Comment: People say that EF can map properties via private setters. [Entity Framework, Private Constructors and Private Setters](http://thedatafarm.com/blog/data-access/entity-framework-private-constructors-and-private-setters/) and SO question [Mapping protected properties in Entity Framework 4.1](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7586538/mapping-protected-properties-in-entity-framework-4-1)

Comment: @IlyaPalkin It's not about what EF can do, it's about keeping persistence details like the ORM in the DAL and not exposing them to the app, to avoid coupling the app to the ORM. And the app objects should not care about how an ORM works or know if you're using one. That's the whole point of the repository.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want o use expressions, then you have to write your very own expression parser which will generate the relevant linq2sql expressions.

A much easier way is to use simple objects, dedicated for the specific criteria

```
public class TaskSelectionCriteria
{
      public Guid? Id {get;set;}
      public string TaskText {get;set;}
}
```

Then in the repo you can check if Id is not null, add *Where(d=>d.Id=criteria.Id.Value)* , if has a TaskTExt, add the corresponding EF condition and so on.

It's not that cool as using expressions, but it's MUCH easier to implement and maintain. And you keep the EF stuff unknown to the rest of the app.